# Normalize entire git repository for PSR coding standards

Tags: git, git-filter-branch, normalize, git-rewrite-history

**An Aside**

There is a way to normalize git repository for line endings.  If your repository has various line endings (Mac, Unix, Windows), they sometimes may be in the way.  So what I did previously was to normalize them all to Unix-style line endings using `git-filter-branch` way described here: http://blog.gyoshev.net/2013/08/normalizing-line-endings-in-git-repositories/

Doing so did not alter my history, in a sense that it was not an intrusive enough change to where my history deltas got messed up in any significant way.  I still can use tools like `blame` to find out who changed the line of code, or `git-bisect` to find out what went wrong where and when.

**What I want to do now**

There is a suggestions to reformat entire codebase to use PSR-compliant formatting.  That means, reformatting entire codebase and committing that to the repository.  Tools like `git-blame` and `git-bisect` will probably stop working after that, all pointing to the same PSR-compliant commit.  I don't like that, since it will inhibit the power of git that I came to enjoy.

**Question**

How do I make my entire repository PSR-compliant when it comes to coding standards, without breaking git power-tools like `git-bisect` and `git-blame`?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer
It is supposed to auto-magically make your code compliant, and it looks like you can use `git-filter-branch` along with it.